# Getting the next and the previous record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying a mysql database table by first creating a temporary table and filling it with data from a select statement.

To test it,i am using a known database id and test if it gets the next and previous records correctly.

This are my functions

```
function get_next($id){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world', 'root', '');
    $db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nr AS SELECT ID,Name,Population FROM city WHERE id > $id ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;");
    $orm = $db->query("SELECT * FROM nr WHERE ID > $id ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;");
    $id = $orm->fetchColumn(0);
    if ($id !== false) {
        return $id;
    }
}
function get_previous($id){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world', 'root', '');
    $db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pr AS SELECT ID,Name,Population FROM city WHERE ID > $id ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;");
    $orm = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pr WHERE ID < $id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;");
    $id = $orm->fetchColumn(0);
    if ($id !== false) {
        return $id;
    }
}
```

I can get the `next` record correctly but i get `previous` record wrong as it says the previous record is the current record.

Am i doing the previous query wrong?.

Comment: No comment on the rest of the question, but you should use bound parameters.

Comment: get_previous - Where id < curent_id. Check record exist
get_next - Where id > curent_id. Check record exist

Answer (score 1):

Your temporary query is looking for IDs greater than your ID, so the next query won't find anything less than that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `DESC` from your `get_previous` function.Replace this line with mine:

```
$orm = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pr WHERE ID < $id ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;");
```

Comment: This worked  `$db->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pr AS SELECT * FROM city");
$orm = $db->query("SELECT * FROM pr WHERE ID < $id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;");`

Comment: yeah the same thing in `create table query` i.e: `WHERE ID < $id`

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a temp table, and since you're only interested in the id you don't need to retrieve other information

```
# To retrieve the previous id:
SELECT MAX(id) FROM city WHERE id < $id
# alternative:
SELECT id FROM city WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

# To retrieve the next id:
SELECT MIN(id) FROM city WHERE id > $id
# alternative:
SELECT id FROM city WHERE id > $id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Getting the next/prev records is easy on a an ordinary table.The problem comes in when i want to get the next and previous records in a dataset from a complicated select statement.

Comment: In that case you just need a more complex query. I don't see why you should use a temp table for that, even more so because you already have your answer when you populate the temp table.

Comment: You are right.I did away with the temp table and it still works.Maybe you confirm this.When i do a select,the select data will be held in a container similar to a table and thus no need to place the data in a temp table?.

Answer (score 0):

Previus row

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Next row

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

I hope this helps...